# What does a Kohen write on his Kasubah (a "regular" kohen and a case of a challal?)

Tags: names, marriage, kohen-priest, ketubah

Normally when a Kohen who still has his regular Kohen status gets married what do we write on his Kasubah?

Ploni HaKohen ben Ploni HaKohen 
or
Ploni ben Ploni HaKohen

As well in the case of someone that is a "challal", what would be written on his Kasubah?

Ploni ben Ploni 
or 
Ploni ben Ploni HaKohen (since his Father is technically still a Kohen.)

(*Note:* If someone could help with an easily understandable definition of "challal" I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There is an issue with language here—please note that it is not the "Kohen's ketubah," but the ketubah of the Kohen's wife. Kettubot are not the "property" of the man, they are documents written for—and designed to remain in the possession of—women.

Comment: @AGV heh. I think most people understood this.

Answer (score 1):

A *challal* gives a *kesuba* that doesn't mention *kehuna* at all. This *chassan* was a challal and his wife a bas-levi:

[image: kesuba]

His father was a kohen:

[image: matzeiva]

(Challal: the son of a challal and a Jewess or of a kohen and devorcee/zona/challala. Zona: was intimate with someone unable to marry her halachically. Challala: daughter of any of the above unions. Notice that the son of a Jew and a challala is not a challal.)

Comment: Who was the masader kedushin?

Comment: @Yehoshua A chassidishe rebbe.

Answer (score 0):

Yout question in the end is easily answerable: A chalal (or a chalala for a girl) is an offspring of a Kohen with a woman whom is forbidden to the Kohen (i.e. a Sonah).

A Kohens kesubah (an other things) are written Ploni ben Ploni HaKohen.

To the best of my knowledge it is the same with a chalal, though i am not 100% on that (not at home otherwise I would check)

Answer (score 0):

I had a case like this--I am a safek challal..We went to a well renowned gadol, with my Rav who was his talmid and he said to write "ki Kohen" and said if he didn't agree with his psak, go ask R' Eliyashiv zt"l.  Apparently the Jerusalem Rabbinate also got very curious and interested in this, so in the end he did and R' Eliyshiv zt"l paskened not to write anything at all after the name.